# Has_many through query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have 2 models (Books and Authors) and a third table joining them (has_many through association).

I am trying to implement search in my app and run a query on both tables. My query looks like this and I cannot figure out the problem:

```
Book.includes(:authors, :author_books).where("books.title LIKE ? OR authors.name = LIKE ?", "%#{book}%", "%#{book}%")
```

This is the error that I get running it:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "authors"
SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE (books.title LIKE '%Harry%' OR authors.name = LIKE '%Harry%')
```

Here is my schema of the three tables:

```
create_table "author_books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "author_id"
    t.bigint "book_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["author_id"], name: "index_author_books_on_author_id"
    t.index ["book_id"], name: "index_author_books_on_book_id"
  end

  create_table "authors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "image"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "rating"
    t.string "critics"
    t.float "price"
  end
```

author_book.rb

```
class AuthorBook < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :author, :book
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :book
end
```

author.rb

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
  has_many :author_book
  has_many :books, through: :author_book
end
```

book.rb

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, uniqueness: true, :case_sensitive => false
  has_many :author_book
  has_many :authors, through: :author_book
  has_many :categories, through: :category_book

  def self.search_book(book)
    if book
      Book.joins(:authors, :author_books).includes(:authors, :author_books).where("books.title LIKE ? OR authors.name = LIKE ?", "%#{book}%", "%#{book}%")
    end
  end  
end
```

I call this search_book method in my book controller like so:

```
def search
    @books = Book.search_book(params[:book])
end
```

Some help, please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [**docs**](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)

> If you want to add conditions to your included models you’ll have to
>   explicitly reference them.

That said, you need to add `references(:authors)` to your query like below to resolve the error

```
Book.includes(:authors, :author_books).where("books.title LIKE ? OR authors.name = LIKE ?", "%#{book}%", "%#{book}%").references(:authors)
```

**Update:**

> Can't join 'Book' to association named 'author_books'; perhaps you
>   misspelled it?

You should replace `has_many :author_book` with `has_many :author_books` and `through: :author_book` with `through: :author_books`

Comment: I added my schema, I am still missing something... The error I'm getting now is "Can't join 'Book' to association named 'author_books'; perhaps you misspelled it?" Could you please take a look?

Comment: @himn Can you update the question with the models code?

Comment: Awesome, that was it. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to join authors and author_books to your relation. `includes` loads both `:author` and `:author_books` but in separate queries.

Try this:

```
Book.joins(:authors, :author_books).includes(:authors, :author_books).where("books.title LIKE ? OR authors.name = LIKE ?", "%#{book}%", "%#{book}%")
```